# Use selectAll() in a GWT TextArea

Tags: gwt, textarea, selectall

My GWT page has a TextArea and I would like it to have the focus and to have all the text selected just when this page is loaded. I try the code below but it does not work at all. Can you help me? Thanks

```
final TextArea myText = new TextArea();
myText.setCharacterWidth(50);
myText.setVisibleLines(20);
myText.setText("Just try something");
RootPanel.get("textContainer").add(myText);
myText.setVisible(true);
myText.setFocus(true);
myText.selectAll();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs of `TextBox.selectAll()` says:

```
This will only work when the widget is attached to the document and not hidden.
```

Most probably your `TextBox` is not yet attached to DOM when you call `.selectAll()`.

Try using `Scheduler`:

```
final TextArea myText = new TextArea();
myText.setCharacterWidth(50);
myText.setVisibleLines(20);
myText.setText("Just try something");
RootPanel.get("textContainer").add(myText);
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            // your commands here
            myText.setVisible(true);
            myText.setFocus(true);
            myText.selectAll();
        }
});
```